# Initializing Magnific Popup with form element (input)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, zepto, magnific-popup

**What I want**:

I want to initialize a modal [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) from a `radio` button on an HTML form. The popup will then display the "send" button.

Actually, I want to initialize the popup by clicking on the *`label`* of the radio input because I'll replace the radio elements with custom CSS radio buttons.

I'm using Zepto because it's lighter and I wouldn't use jQuery otherwise.

**What's the problem**:

1. If I click on a `label`, I do get a Magnific modal, but the `radio` option **doesn't get selected**.
2. If I click on the `radio` button itself, the option **does get selected** and the modal appears. ***But***, if I dismiss the modal to choose *another* `option`, the modal appears without changing the option. *(This is not usable anyway because I'll hide the stock radio buttons — as previously mentioned).*

**My code**: (http://jsfiddle.net/Nkc5X/)

HTML:

```
<form action="#">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="whatside" title="Left" value="Left">
        <span>Left</span>
    </label>

    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="whatside" title="Right" value="Right">
        <span>Right</span>
    </label>

    <div id="modal" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
        <h2>Modal dialog</h2>
            <button type="submit" value="Send">Send</button> 
        <a class="popup-modal-dismiss" href="#">Dismiss</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('label').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        items: {src: '#modal'},
        preloader: false,
        modal: true
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.popup-modal-dismiss', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.magnificPopup.close();
    });
});
```

**What I've tried**:

I've several tried variations on my html/javascript to no avail. I've tried initializing the popup using different selectors (`label` and `input` elements, class, id).

Comment: Well it seems like it does what you want it to do, except setting the radio value. Why dont you just do this per JS when the label is clicked? or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks @Fonzy, your suggestion made me think of a different way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I left this problem simmer for a while and finally found a solution.

I initialize the popup from the `input` element: `$('input').magnificPopup`, which allows me to select the option when clicking on the `label`.

I reset the form controls using native JavaScript, [using the method described in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452699/how-to-reset-a-form-using-jquery-with-reset-method#answer-21514788): `$('form')[0].reset();`

Working JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nkc5X/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        items: {src: '#modal'},
        preloader: false,
        modal: true
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.popup-modal-dismiss', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.magnificPopup.close();
        $('form')[0].reset();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
 $.magnificPopup.open({
       items: {
            src: '<div class="my-container">here is the content of the html you want to popup</div>'
       },
       callbacks: {//this is optional
           close: function () {
                //do something on exit
           }
       }
 });
```