# Reset a page in ASP.NET without postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reset, requiredfieldvalidator

I want to reset a form but I'm using a few "Required Field Validator" every time I click the reset button the error message shows requiring fields... What I tried:

```
ReuiqredFieldValidator.Enabled = false; 
TextBox.Text="";


Response.Redirect("Samepage.aspx");
Response.Redirect("Request.RawUrl");

<input type=reset>
```

Comment: why do not try jquery?

Comment: did you try setting CausesValidation=false for reset button. But In that case you have to make the reset button a server control. <asp:Button id="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Reset"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:Button 
runat="server" 
ID="reBt" 
Text="Reset" 
OnClientClick="this.form.reset();return false;" 
CausesValidation="false"
/>
```

from [here](http://www.jasinskionline.com/TechnicalWiki/Creating-A-Reset-Button.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `ValidationGroup` property to group of controls and the relevant `asp button` and do not provide `ValidationGroup` to reset button.

Or same can be achieved vice-versa

This is applicable as you using asp.net controls

Refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can try it

```
<input type="reset" causesvalidation="False">
```

It should work.

It works for `input submit` so I think it should work on `input reset` also.

Details [Input =submit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputbutton.causesvalidation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

### Edit 1

Or if you are using jQuery you can use like this

```
$(':input','#myform')
 .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
 .val('')
 .removeAttr('checked')
 .removeAttr('selected');
```

References

1. [Clear form fields with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery)
2. [How to reset a form using jQuery with .reset() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452699/how-to-reset-a-form-using-jquery-with-reset-method)

jQuery reference

[:reset Selector](http://api.jquery.com/reset-selector/)

Comment: @majidgeek visit this it is for .net framework 4.5 [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputbutton.causesvalidation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)