# reset form fields after submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Hello I m using jquery validations , my form is validating and submitting successfully but the fields containing the previous data, i want to reset the fields after submitting the form.

the `$('#frm').reset(); is not working.`

```
submitHandler: function(form)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "contact_submit.php",
        type: "post",
        data: $("#frm").serialize(),
        success:function(response)                  
        {
            if(response)
            {
                $('#msg-valid').html('<img src="img/valid.png">Your form is submited, Thank You !');
                $('#frm').reset();
            }
            else{
                $('#msg-error').html('<img src="img/error.png">Your form is not submited');                         
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset a form using jQuery with .reset() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452699/how-to-reset-a-form-using-jquery-with-reset-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically `.reset()` is a native javascript function. You are trying to invoke it from wrapped Jquery object. So probabbly it would have caused error in your `console`, So in order to access it, first you have to extract the javascript object from the Jquery object then invoke that function like,

```
$('#frm')[0].reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$('#frm')[0].reset();
```

It will clear the form fields

Answer (score 0):

I found that,the following code reset the form after submit.

```
submitHandler: function(form)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "contact_submit.php",
                type: "post",
                data: $("#frm").serialize(),
                success:function(response)

                {
                    if(response)
                    {
                    $('#msg-valid').html('<img src="img/valid.png">Your form is submited, Thank You !');

                        $(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden, :checkbox, :radio').val('');
                        $(':checkbox, :radio').prop('checked', false);

                    }
                    else{
                        $('#msg-error').html('<img src="img/error.png">Your form is not submited');

                    }
                }

            });

        }
```