# Handling multiple forms in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

If I have something like this in some page in my project:

```
<div class="dialog" title="Basic dialog" id="popup">
    <div class="text"> </div>
</div>

<c:url value="/${entity}/cadastra" var="cadastra"/>
<form:form method="POST" action="${cadastra}" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">cadastrar</button>
</form:form>
```

and the submit event is handled by this code:

```
$('form.form').ajaxForm(function(data) {
    if(data == '')
        $('#yes').css('display', 'block');
    else
        $('#not').css('display', 'block');

    $('<<element>>').each(function(){
        this.reset();
    });
});
```

anyone knows what should be the value for <> if I want reset only the fields from the form I submit, and I could have a new form, with the same class, inside `div.dialog`?

If I use `form.form` both forms are reseted, and if I use `this`, I get an error. Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Add a name attribute to your form, select the form in the dialog with a more precise selector like ".dialog form", or select forms by name 'form[name="myform"]'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you are uncertain about access to elements within a plugin you can always initialize them individiually within an `each` loop.

Within `each` `this` will be the element instance and you can store it as variable to pass into plugin.

```
$('form.form').each(function () {
    /* assign "this" to variable that can be used inside plugin */
    var form = this;
    $(form).ajaxForm(function (data) {
        if (data == '') {
            $('#yes').css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            $('#not').css('display', 'block');
        }
        form.reset();
    });
});
```

Comment: Excellent answer to a challenging question. Bravo! I love the elegance of the solution and I can tell that you took the time to really understand what he was trying to do. Javascript closures always blow my mind.