# How do I toggle between enabling and disabling a form submittion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Here's the skinny: In the below code `#new-org-btn` is an `input` of type `submit` and I want it to only submit its containing `form` if the `click` function reaches the `else` statement. As of now, it is submitting even it doesn't reach the `else` statement.

```
$('#new-org-btn').click(function() {
    var newOrgName = $('#new-org-ipt').val();
    console.log(newOrgName.length);;
    if (newOrgName.length == 0)
    {
        $('#new-org-output-msg').css('color', 'red').text("New organization not submitted. Name cannot be blank.");
    }
    else if (newOrgName.indexOf('-') == -1)
    {
        $('#new-org-output-msg').css('color', 'red').text("New organization not submitted. Name cannot contain any '-' characters.");  
    }
    else
    {
        $('#new-org-output-msg').css('color', 'green');
        $('#new-org-form').submit();                
    }                            
});
```

I know that `$('#new-org-form').submit(function() { return false; });` would disable the form from doing anything when it submits, but the problem is that if I do

```
$('#new-org-btn').click(function() {
    var newOrgName = $('#new-org-ipt').val();
    console.log(newOrgName.length);;
    if (newOrgName.length == 0)
    {
        $('#new-org-output-msg').css('color', 'red').text("New organization not submitted. Name cannot be blank.");
        $('new-org-form').submit(function() { return false; });

    }
    else if (newOrgName.indexOf('-') == -1)
    {
        $('#new-org-output-msg').css('color', 'red').text("New organization not submitted. Name cannot contain any '-' characters.");
        $('new-org-form').submit(function() { return false; });  
    }
    else
    {
        $('#new-org-output-msg').css('color', 'green');
        $('#new-org-form').submit();                
    }                            
});
```

then when I actually enter the else statement and want to submit the form as usual, it may have been deactivated from a previous call to the function. I therefore need a way to "reactivate" the form. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it a bit differently:

Do checking only upon submit, not on click itself - this is better as both submit button and "enter" key would be handled:

```
$('#form').submit(function(ev) {

        var newOrgName = $('#new-org-ipt').val();
        if (newOrgName.length == 0)
        {
            $('#new-org-output-msg').css('color', 'red').text("New organization not submitted. Name cannot be blank.");
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
        else if (newOrgName.indexOf('-') == -1)
        {
            $('#new-org-output-msg').css('color', 'red').text("New organization not submitted. Name cannot contain any '-' characters.");
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#new-org-output-msg').css('color', 'green');
        }                            
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `#new-org-btn` is of type `submit`, it is going to submit regardless. Therefore, you need to `return false` in the `if` and `else if`

```
$('#new-org-btn').click(function() {
        var newOrgName = $('#new-org-ipt').val();
        console.log(newOrgName.length);;
        if (newOrgName.length == 0)
        {
            $('#new-org-output-msg').css('color', 'red').text("New organization not submitted. Name cannot be blank.");
            return false;
        }
        else if (newOrgName.indexOf('-') == -1)
        {
            $('#new-org-output-msg').css('color', 'red').text("New organization not submitted. Name cannot contain any '-' characters.");
            return false;  
        }
        else
        {
            $('#new-org-output-msg').css('color', 'green');
            //$('#new-org-form').submit(); not need if new-org-form is the form itself                
        }                            
    });
```

Regarding

*>  ...need a way to "reactivate" the form...*

```
$('form')[0].reset();//may need to change selector if you have multiple forms
```

should do the trick.

See [How to reset a form using jQuery with .reset() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452699/how-to-reset-a-form-using-jquery-with-reset-method)

Comment: Additionally, $('#new-org-form').submit(); in your solution's last line is not necessary because, as you said, it is going to submit regardless. Am I right?