# How to reset an individual input element with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-input

How do I reset an individual input element with JQuery (is it JQuery, or JavaScript)?

[How to reset a form using jQuery with .reset() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452699/how-to-reset-a-form-using-jquery-with-reset-method) shows how to reset an entire form, but I want to reset individual elements, not the entire form.

Comment: `$('#myinputid').val('');`

Comment: @usandfriends that's assuming the original value was `''`.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the original value of an input element with the defaultValue attribute.

For example you can do this:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");

myInput.value = myInput.defaultValue;
```

Comment: This seems a better answer. Made a fiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/m7e0277t/2/

Answer (score 2):

You might need to use a hack for this.

Use `.wrap()` to temporarily wrap the required input with a form.

```js
$('#input1,#input2').val('testUpdated');
$('#input1').wrap('<form/>');
$('#input1').closest('form')[0].reset();
$('#input1').unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input id="input1" value="test"/>
    <input id="input2" value="test"/>
</form>
```

Comment: i mean, i find your idea clever. why not append a `<form>` to the body, move the input in there, reset the form, and re-move the input to its original position? although, i dont know how important it is to reset the input in the original form.

Comment: Even if the input is already in a form, you can temporarily wrap another form. Chek here http://jsfiddle.net/m7e0277t/1/

Answer (score 1):

If the value has been set in the input element, then it can be referenced back to

```js
 $('#resetName').click(function () {
     $('#name').val($('#name').attr('value'));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="TEST" id="name"></input>
    <input value="99" id="age"></input>
    <input value="1 Apr 2000" id="DOB"></input>
    
    <button id="resetName" value="Reset Name">Reset Name</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Resetting a single input field with jQuery:

```
$('#myField').val($('#myField').prop("defaultValue"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple

```
$('#escape').on('click', function(e){
                        $('#field').val($('#field').defaultValue);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/g47z97kt/1/)

TRY USING `$(this).val(defaultVal);` as

```
('#maincontainer').find('textarea,input[type=text]').each(function () {
        var defaultVal = $(this).data('default');
        $(this).val(defaultVal);
    });
```

Change the ID if you want a specific input to be cleared here i just show how to clear input and textarea in general

Comment: When I test it, `$(this).data('default')` returns undefined. Is this the desired behaviour?

Comment: you should put default as blank i didnt know you need that kind of info the question merely states reset the input

Comment: without explicitly defining `data-default` this will return `undefined` and hence is not very practical

Comment: I have been reading the question several times but it didnt mention that he needs to get the value all he wants is to reset the input and this example does that but thanks anyway