# How to reset form fields the elegant way with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I reset the form fields more elegant compared to the code below? The code is working. But if I have lots of form fields it does not look so nice. Is there a more compact way?

```
<script>
        function setSearchCriteria(){
            var searchcriteria = document.getElementById("TherapistSearch-SearchCriteria");
            searchcriteria.value = "";
        }
        function setCity(){
            var city = document.getElementById("TherapistSearch-City");
            city.value = "";
        }
        function setLastName(){
            var lastname = document.getElementById("TherapistSearch-LastName");
            lastname.value = "";
        }
        function setFirstName(){
            var firstname = document.getElementById("TherapistSearch-FirstName");
            firstname.value = "";
        }
}
</script>

<input  type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset form" 
onclick="javascript:clearForms();javascript:setSearchCriteria();setCity();setLastName();setFirstName();" title="Reset form"/>
```

Comment: Why not just change the reset button from `type="button"` to `type="reset"`, then it's automatic, and about as simple and elegant as it could possibly be.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452699/how-to-reset-a-form-using-jquery-with-reset-method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear form fields with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Give a css class to your input fields.

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" class="resettable" />
<input type="text" id="firstName" class="resettable" />
<select id="states" class="selectResettable">
  <option value="0">Select an option </option>
  <option value="1">Michigan</option>
  <option value="2">Ohio</option>
<select>
<input type="button" id="resetBtn" />
```

And use this css class(es) as jQuery selector(s) to get all of this inputs and set the value to empty/default value. I also removed the `onclick` from button HTML markup as we are going to do it in the [unobtrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) way.

Add this javascript where we are registering the code for the `click` event on our button.

```
$(function(){

   $("#resetBtn").click(function(e){
       alert("Reset button clicked");
       //Set the input text fields to empty string
       $("input.resettable").val("");

       //Reset the dropdowns.
       $(".selectResettable").val("0")
       //If you want to do something else, Do it here.
   });

});
```

Comment: Also, you can create another CSS class for dropdowns or other types of input - for dropdowns you can always have a listitem with the text "Select an Option" with a value of "0".  Then, in your reset function: $(".DropDownCSSClass").val("0");

Comment: Absolutely. I added that to the answer for future readers. Thanks for pointing that out @StanShaw

Answer (score 2):

Simply use HTML the way it's meant to be used, and take advantage of the reset button:

```
<input  type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset form" title="Reset form"/>
```

This requires no JavaScript, no additional functionality, and is a native component of HTML forms. Using `type="button"` gives the element the appearance of a button, but strips the default functionality; using `type="reset"` gives the appearance of a button and gives the default functionality of resetting the parent `<form>` element to its default page-load state.

References:

- [`<input>` element `type` attribute-values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-type).

Comment: It's possible that he may not want to clear out every single field on his form.

Comment: It is, but if so that should be mentioned in the question (I'll happily add additional information that I might think is beneficial, but I'm not a fan of guessing what the OP wants).

Comment: Correct - I was just pointing out that input type="reset" will reset all of your form fields for clarity's sake.  I prefer to use classes and jQuery since the code is minimal and is infinitely more flexible.  Good answer, though!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="reset" id="resetBtn" class="resettable" />
```

use reset type of button or call reset method on form as below

```
<input  type="button" 
                                    class="btn btn-default"                                 
                                    value="Reset form" 
                                    onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').reset();" 
                                    title="Reset form"/>
```