# How to reset input field? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've read several posts, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452699/how-to-reset-a-form-using-jquery-with-reset-method), but I can't seem to get the input field to clear out after submitting. What is the most basic / elementary way to do this?

Currently I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form[name=checkListForm]').on('submit', function() {
          // prevent the form from submitting
          event.preventDefault();
          var toAdd = $(this).find('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
          $('.list').append("<div class='item'>" + toAdd + "</div>")
          $('input[name=checkListItem').reset();
        });
});
```

My HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">     
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>To Do</h2>
    <form name="checkListForm">
      <input type="text" name="checkListItem" />
      <button type="submit" id="button">Add!</button>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <div class="list"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Single line of code to handle all the fields `$(formselector)[0].reset();`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Instead of resetting, just set a blank value to the input field using this bit of code:

```
$('input[name=checkListItem').val('');
```

In order to reset all inputs in a particular form you could also use the following code (using the `:input` selector):

```
$('form :input').val('');
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. As a side question, do you know why the selector should be `input[name=checkListItem` and not `form[name=checkListForm`?

Comment: @AlanH: Because you want to set input's value to be blank, not form's.

Comment: @AlanH : that's because the `input` selector basically selects a form control and it has a value that can be set, whereas ``$('form')`` basically means you're selecting an html element itself rather than a form control, since the `$('form')`  does not have a value attribute unlike the `input ` selector, see my latest edit to the answer as well.

Comment: When you use `element[attribute=value]` your filtering the elements/nodes - ie it selects all of type `element` then from those, only the one with `[attribute=value]` so `form[name]` find all **forms** with name attribute.  If you did `form [name]` (ie with a space) then it would find all elements with name attribute inside the form.

Comment: $('input[name=checkListItem]').val(''); you have missed ']' ;)

Comment: Reset a form through the `reset()`. it's valid both for JavaScript and jQuery and clears all form elements besides inputs.

Answer (score 2):

This should work,(I've tested it myself).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form[name=checkListForm]').on('submit', function() {
          //other code
          $('input[name=checkListItem]').val("")
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me; Few modification to. I use `function(e)` and `e.preventDefault()` and used `$('input[name=checkListItem').val('');` instead of reset()

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form[name=checkListForm]').on('submit', function(e) {
              // prevent the form from submitting
              e.preventDefault();
              var toAdd = $(this).find('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
              $('.list').append("<div class='item'>" + toAdd + "</div>")


              $('input[name=checkListItem').val('');
            });
    });
 </script>

<h2>To Do</h2>
<form name="checkListForm">
  <input type="text" name="checkListItem" />
  <button type="submit" id="button">Add!</button>
</form>
<br/>
<div class="list"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can write after submission.

```
document.getElementById("myform").reset();
```

Comment: This resets the entire form, not the field, as the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myForm').on('submit', function() {
$('#checkListItem').val('');
});
});
```