# jQuery that runs on Chrome & Safari, doesn't run on Firefox, Edge & Brave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and have picked up writing JavaScript after a long time. I am struggling with a piece of code that works well on Chrome & Safari but doesn't work on Firefox, Edge & Brave, all running on Mac OS.

**PHP Page:**

```
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // Captcha Script
  var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
  var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
  var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
  var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
  var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
  
  var code = a + b + c + d + e;
  document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code;
  document.getElementById("CaptchaDiv").innerHTML = code;
  
  
  </script>

    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 animated"
        data-animation="fadeInRight" data-animation-delay="300">
        <div class="hme-cntct w-100 float-left">
            <form id="contact-form">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="display: none">
                        <p id="errmsg"></p>
                    </div>
                    <!--col-6-->

                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                        <p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name"
                                name="first_name" required>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--col-6-->

                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                        <p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name"
                                name="last_name" required>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--col-6-->
                </div>
                <!--row-->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                        <p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email"
                                required class="email">
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--col-6-->

                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                        <p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" name="phone"
                                required class="number">
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--col-6-->

                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <p>
                            <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" required></textarea>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--col-6-->
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <p>
                        <div class="capbox">
                            <div id="CaptchaDiv"></div>
                            <div class="capbox-inner">
                                Type the number:<br> <input type="hidden"
                                    name="txtCaptcha" id="txtCaptcha"> <input
                                    type="text" name="CaptchaInput" id="CaptchaInput"
                                    size="15" maxlength="5" required><br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--col-6-->
                </div>
                <!--row-->


                <div class="cntct-sbmt w-100 float-left">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"
                        id="submit" class="submit">
                </div>
                <!--cntct-sbmt-->
            </form>
        </div>
        <!--hme-cntct-->
    </div>
    <!--col-6-->
```

**Custom.js:**

```
    $(document).on("click", ".submit" , function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#contact-form").validate({
            rules: {
                CaptchaInput: { equalTo: "#txtCaptcha" }
          },
            messages: {
                CaptchaInput: "Please enter valid captcha!"
          }
        });
        if($("#contact-form").valid()) {
            $.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              url: 'https://footballfanapp.com/contactform.php',
              data:  $('form').serializeArray(),
              success:function(data){
                  data = JSON.parse(data);
                  $("#errmsg").html(data.message);
                  $("#errmsg").parent().show();
                  $("#errmsg").closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");  
                  // $("#contact-form").reset();

                  var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
                  var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
                  var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
                  var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
                  var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
                  var code = a + b + c + d + e;
                  document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code;
                  document.getElementById("CaptchaDiv").innerHTML = code;
              }
            });
      
          }  
        });
```

What I am trying to do is to submit the form after validation and if the call is successful displaying a confirmation message and resetting form field and Captcha.

Can you please help me pointing out what is missing to make this run on all 4 browsers

Comment: So what part of it is "broken". Like what is it doing versus what the expected result is.

Comment: Once the form is submitted, the code sends an email and then is expected to reset the form and display a confirmation message. This is all working fine on Safari & Chrome but on other browsers, after sending email the form doesn't reset and the confirmation is not displayed. So I think the function doesn't gets called after successful ajax call.               
                  success:function(data){
                  data = JSON.parse(data); ...
                  $("#errmsg").html(data.message);
                  $("#errmsg").parent().show(); ....

Comment: You have `$("#contact-form").reset();` commented out. So for all I know, it could be an expected result for chrome and safari to clear the form after submission.

Comment: As for the `$("#errmsg").parent().show();`, I am uncertain. console.log() it?

Comment: "$("#contact-form").reset();" never worked hence I commented it.

Comment: Sorry, was eating. My hunch is that chrome and safari clears the form upon submission. If you wanted to clear it in other browsers, you'd likely have to select the elements of form and programmatically reset their values. Apparently you can use `$('#form_id').trigger("reset");` to reset the form: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452699/how-to-reset-a-form-using-jquery-with-reset-method

Comment: Thanks, the reset works on its own but when I run reset in my code block it doesn't work. I think the way AJAX call is made and json is parsed affects Firefox and other browsers but is good for Chrome & Safari.